# Check if SharePoint field exists using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I want to use a script that checks if a field called Delivery Terms exists in a form, and if this is true, a function should be executed.

Why does the following not work?

```
if ($('nobr:contains("Delivery Terms")').length > 0) {
    $jq(document).ready(function () {
        {
            $jq().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
                relationshipList: "Machine",
                relationshipListParentColumn: "Costing_x0020_Group_x003a__x0020",
                relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
                parentColumn: "Manufacturing Unit",
                childColumn: "Machine",
                debug: true
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the full code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Fixes the design for dropdowns with more than 20 items 
$jq().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
 columnName: "Responsible Designer/Quoter"
});
$jq().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
 columnName: "Material No. 1"
});
$jq().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
 columnName: "Material No. 2"
});

if ($('nobr:contains("Delivery Terms")').length > 0) {
    $jq(document).ready(function () {
        {
        $jq().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList:"Machine",
            relationshipListParentColumn:"Costing_x0020_Group_x003a__x0020",
            relationshipListChildColumn:"Title",
            parentColumn:"Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn:"Machine",
            debug:true
        });
        $jq().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList:"Art no",
            relationshipListParentColumn:"Costing_x0020_Group_x003a__x0020",
            relationshipListChildColumn:"Title",
            parentColumn:"Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn:"Material No. 1",
            debug:true
        }); 
        $jq().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList:"Art no",
            relationshipListParentColumn:"Costing_x0020_Group_x003a__x0020",
            relationshipListChildColumn:"Title",
            parentColumn:"Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn:"Material No. 2",
            debug:true
        });
        $jq().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList:"Approval",
            relationshipListParentColumn:"Title",
            relationshipListChildColumn:"Reason",
            parentColumn:"Issue Status",
            childColumn:"Reason to decline",
            debug:true
        });
        $jq().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList:"Responsible Designer",
            relationshipListParentColumn:"Costing_x0020_Group_x003a__x0020",
            relationshipListChildColumn:"Title",
            parentColumn:"Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn:"Responsible Designer/Quoter",
            debug:true
        });

        $jq().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList:"Delivery Terms",
            relationshipListParentColumn:"Manufacturing_x0020_Place",
            relationshipListChildColumn:"Title",
            parentColumn:"Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn:"Delivery Terms",
            debug:true
        });

        $jq().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList:"Payment Terms",
            relationshipListParentColumn:"Manufacturing_x0020_Place",
            relationshipListChildColumn:"Title",
            parentColumn:"Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn:"Payment Terms",
            debug:true
         });
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: What does inputting `$('nobr:contains("Delivery Terms")').length` into the console log produce?

Comment: Where is this code? Are you sure that the field exists in the DOM when you run that condition? You can solve these issues by simply placing your `if` statement inside `$jq(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: I get a JS error on the page saying Expected ')'

Answer (score 0):

It seems "$('nobr:contains("Delivery Terms")').length" is not what you need. Try one of these:

```
$('nobr:contains("Delivery Terms")').val().length
$('nobr:contains("Delivery Terms")').text().length
```

Also, check that selector "nobr:contains("Delivery Terms")" found desired element, may be its empty and code not calling then.

Comment: Does "nobr:contains("Delivery Terms")" mean that I check for a value given by the user? I want to check if the column exists in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your if statement inside document.ready

```
//Fixes the design for dropdowns with more than 20 items 
$().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
    columnName: "Responsible Designer/Quoter"
});
$().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
    columnName: "Material No. 1"
});
$().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
    columnName: "Material No. 2"
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('nobr:contains("Delivery Terms")').length > 0) {
        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList: "Machine",
            relationshipListParentColumn: "Costing_x0020_Group_x003a__x0020",
            relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
            parentColumn: "Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn: "Machine",
            debug: true
        });
        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList: "Art no",
            relationshipListParentColumn: "Costing_x0020_Group_x003a__x0020",
            relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
            parentColumn: "Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn: "Material No. 1",
            debug: true
        });
        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList: "Art no",
            relationshipListParentColumn: "Costing_x0020_Group_x003a__x0020",
            relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
            parentColumn: "Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn: "Material No. 2",
            debug: true
        });
        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList: "Approval",
            relationshipListParentColumn: "Title",
            relationshipListChildColumn: "Reason",
            parentColumn: "Issue Status",
            childColumn: "Reason to decline",
            debug: true
        });
        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList: "Responsible Designer",
            relationshipListParentColumn: "Costing_x0020_Group_x003a__x0020",
            relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
            parentColumn: "Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn: "Responsible Designer/Quoter",
            debug: true
        });

        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList: "Delivery Terms",
            relationshipListParentColumn: "Manufacturing_x0020_Place",
            relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
            parentColumn: "Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn: "Delivery Terms",
            debug: true
        });

        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList: "Payment Terms",
            relationshipListParentColumn: "Manufacturing_x0020_Place",
            relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
            parentColumn: "Manufacturing Unit",
            childColumn: "Payment Terms",
            debug: true
        });
    }
});

</script>
```